# What can the reason be for making use of this strange namespace trick?

Tags: c++, namespaces, alias, namespace-alias

Why would I want to write something like this and fill `// STUFF` with stuff?

```cpp
// boost
namespace another_name {} namespace boost = another_name; namespace another_name {
// STUFF
}
```

Comment: sdt -> std ? Where exactly did you see it? Context may matter, and as you don't know what it does it may well be that you left out relevant parts

Comment: Context matter really much when it comes to the `std` namespace, as almost all attempt to put something in it leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: also messing around with the `boost` namespace I would not expect to work out well for anybody but `boost` itself. You need to clarify. The code as posted does not do anything useful

Comment: @molbdnilo Why would this not compile? It's simply namespace aliasing obscucered by lack of line breaks.

Comment: @dfri The original premise, before the question was edited, was that the namespace already exists.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see, I missed that the OP had a ninja-edit (I've covered that case in my answer).

Comment: @molbdnilo, I mistakenly thought that namespaces was in scope. It wasn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a regular [namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) definition followed by a [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) definition aliasing the former.

```
// Namespace definition of namespace 'another_name'.
namespace another_name {} 

// Namespace alias definition, 'boost' aliases 'another_name'.
namespace boost = another_name; 

// Namespace (re-)definition: open up the declarative region
// described by the namespace 'another_name' to add e.g.
// function declarations, definitions and so on.
namespace another_name {
    void foo() {}
}

// foo() is available via the namespace alias 'boost'.

int main() { boost::foo(); }
```

Note however that defining an alias name `boost` could conflict with an actual namespace `boost`

> ```
>  namespace alias_name = ...
> ```
>
> ... `alias_name` **must be a name not previously used** ...

such that as soon as you actually include a boost header you will run into a compiler error:

```
// Existing namespace(s)
namespace boost {}
namespace another_name {} 

// Conflicing alias_name.
namespace boost = another_name;  // error: redefinition of 'boost
```

---

If you've seen this particular example in a code base, it could be an attempt at providing an internal what seems-to-be boost (subset) implementation of boost that could later be replaced by removing the alias and including the actual boost headers, but without having to change call sites that explicitly qualifies entities using `boost::`.

E.g., an early version of the code base (before using actual boost):

```
// internal_boost_like_impl.h
namespace internal_boost_like_impl {
    // Until-boost implementation of boost::mp11::mp_identity.
    namespace mp11 {
        template<typename T>
        struct mp_identity {
            using type = T;
        };
        
        template<typename T>
        using mp_identity_t = typename mp_identity<T>::type;
    }
}

// internal_boost.h
#include "internal_boost_like_impl.h"
namespace boost = internal_boost_like_impl;

// Code base looks to be using boost, but actually 
// uses implementations from internal_boost_like_impl.
#include "internal_boost.h"
template<typename T>
struct Foo { T t; };

template<typename T>
void addToFoo(Foo<T>& foo,  
              boost::mp11::mp_identity_t<T> val) { foo.t += val; }
                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ T in non-deduced context.
```

where later `internal_boost.h` is modified into

```
// internal_boost.h
#include "boost/mpl/identity.hpp"
```

This approach could arguably facilitate variants easier (say one product variant where 3rd party libs may not be used due to e.g. safety critical concerns) but it may also confuse developers, and an arguably better approach would be to provide a unique alias that is simply set to different values for different variants/versions (rather than providing an alias that is named as and later entirely replaced by an actual well-known namespace such as `boost`).